# Load CSV values then search for matches in mysql database

Tags: mysql, arrays, csv, match

I'm trying to build a script for a cron job that loads some values from a CSV file. This CSV file has 2 fields

```
product_id 
price
```

The script will load the values from CSV, then it searches in mysql table for product_id matches. If found, it will update the price for that particular matched product_id in the table with the corresponding price in CSV.

I reached the below code so far but I got stuck at the part where I need to compare the array values from CSV with the array values from mysql.

```
<?php
// DB part
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','user','pass','db');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }

mysqli_select_db($con,"products");

        $sql="SELECT product_id, price, FROM products";

        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

// CSV part
$file_handle = fopen("prices.csv", "r");


while (!feof($file_handle) ) {

    $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);

    $code = str_replace(' ', '', $line_of_text[0]); // 
    $price = str_replace(' ', '', $line_of_text[1]); // 



     if (in_array($code, str_replace(' ', '', $row)))
          {
          echo "Match found";
          print $code . " - " . $price . "<br />";
          }
            else
          {
          echo "Match not found";
          print $code . " - " . $price . "<br />";
          }
    }
fclose($file_handle);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Discover [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

Comment: I did read about that but the problem is that the user that creates the CSV file does not insert product_ids exactly as in the database, sometimes only a part of it, and because of that multiple matches can be found in the database, each cotaining part of that product_id and I need to make a report.txt of those duplicates and those not found and email them back to the user so he can recheck the product_ids and update the CSV.

Comment: That is why I want to check the values against those in the table, and if only one is found, update the price, if more than one are found do not update and report them by email and those that are not found, report them too. This will be run as a cron-job each week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're storing just the first line of your *products* table in `$row`. Then you are doing some hard-to-understand comparisons, but all of those comparisons compare just your first row.

Here's what I'd do:

```
// Untested Code Below, Not Suited For Production Use

// ...
// open the DB connection, open the file, etc.
// ...

// iterate over the complete CSV file
while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
    $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
    $product_id = clean_product_id($line_of_text[0]);
    $price = $line_of_text[1];
    // for any entry in the CSV file check if there is more than one result
    $sql="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products WHERE product_id='$product_id'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    if( $row[0] == 1 ) {
        // update the table price for the corresponding row (product), if there is just a single result for this $product_id
        $sql="UPDATE products SET price = '$price' WHERE product_id='$product_id' LIMIT 1"; // in production code use mysqli_real_escape_string() on $price and $product_id!
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    } else {
        // if there are more results for this $product_id, add an error to your report.txt file
    }
}
```

Comment: It fails with time-out, probably because my database table contains over 500.000 products.
Isn't there a way to scan the database table only once and then compare each CSV line against the values ?

Comment: Is there an index on the `product_id` field? If there is, 500,000 products shouldn't be a problem. When is the timeout happening? Happens it while calling MySQL or is the PHP script terminated because of exceeding the `max_execution_time` time? If the latter is the case, then your CSV file is to large. Split it up in smaller chunks or increase `max_execution_time` in php.ini.

Comment: Well, I just added an index on that column.
The CSV is only 28 KB and 1900 lines, it will never exceed lets say 3000 lines. 
The max_exec_time is set to 999 for some other tests.
I get 500 internal server error after abou 20 secs of loading.

Comment: Just did a test with only 10 lines in the CSV and that way it works, though it takes about 3 seconds.

Comment: You should find out why there is an internal server error. Sometimes it's easier running the PHP script from the command line, because you can directly see the problem. Nevertheless I suspect your error has to do with a timeout while connecting to the database.

Comment: It works but only with about 50 - 70 lines in the CSV. Not good

Comment: What's happening then? What error do you get? If it works for 50 lines, then it most likely is some kind of timeout on the PHP side. Running from the command line, PHP uses probably another php.ini file as running via HTTP. Perhaps the `max_execution_time` is much lower there.

Comment: I'm going to run it as a cron-job with all 1900 lines CSV and get back !

Comment: It fails in cron-job too if I let it do 1900 lines !

Comment: Sorry, but I can't help you if you don't post any error messages! Start the script from the command line and tell us what kind of error you get.

Comment: It finally worked as cron. It took some minutes but it does work. I did modified it a bit. It does what I want, with some bugs though.